# Laravel: Dynamic email content on API

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am building an email API on Laravel. I want to send emails via this API on my other projects. I send emails successfully through this API. However, the email content is hardcoded on the client side. For example:

```
$body = "Dear $user->name,<br />
         Thank you for your order.";

$client->request('POST', 'http://api.test/send_mail?token=' . $token, ['form_params' => [
                'from' => 'client@test.com',
                'title' => 'API Test Mail',
                'to' => 'customer@test.com',
                'body' => $body,
                'signature' => 'Regards'
            ]]);
```

My aim is especially creating dynamic `email body` without hardcoded. So, I save email content to the database. My plan is to trigger the saved email content with request on the client side. After some researches on email systems with similar structures, I think, I have to save the related content to the database like this format:

```
Dear {{ username }}
Thank you for your order.
```

By this way, I will only send the `username` info to the API from the client side. I will not have to deal with HTML email content.

However, I am not sure about what to do after this stage. How can I send and parse the `$username` info to the API from the client side? Do I have to add request to the API on every single parameters? Here is my current request rules:

```
return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'from' => 'required|email',
            'to' => 'required|email',
            'body' => 'required',
            'signature' => 'nullable',
            'email_template' => 'nullable'
        ];
```

Also this is my mail markdown:

```
@component('mail::message')

    {!! $mail['body'] !!}

    @if(array_key_exists('signature', $mail))
        <p>{!! $mail['signature'] !!}</p>
    @endif
@endcomponent
```

Actually, dynamic parameters will be child members of the `body`. If I want to add `$username` as a dynamic variable to the email body, should I add it to the rules of the request and also to the mail markdown? If so, I have to do some static transactions on every saved different email contents and their different parameters.

How can I build this structure in a clearer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You should parse every parameters to your API.
You may do like this:

```
$data['username'] = 'John';
$data['other'] = 'other';

$client->request('POST', 'http://api.test/send_mail?token=' . $token, 
            ['form_params' => 
             [
                'from' => 'client@test.com',
                'title' => 'API Test Mail',
                'to' => 'customer@test.com',
                'data' => $data,
                'signature' => 'Regards',
                'template_id' => 'template_id' // parse if you have multi templates
            ]]);
```

And you can send email like this in API controller.

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
  
     $template = Template::findorfail($request->template_id);
     
     $body = $template->body;// this is template dynamic body. You may get other parameters too from database. $title = $template->title; $from = $template->from;

     foreach($request->data as $key=>$parameter)
     {
          $body = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $parameter, $body); // this will replace {{username}} with $data['username']
     }

    $request->body = $body;
    $mailObject = new MyMail($request); // you can make php artisan make:mail MyMail
    Mail::to($request->to)->send($mailObject);

}
...
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $request;
  
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request= $request;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->request['title'])
            ->from($this->request['from'])
            ->markdown('components.mail.myTemplate');
    }
}
```

Then in `myTemplate.blade.php` you can render `{!!$request['body'] !}}`

Hope this helps you.